# generalization of fundamental theorem of algebra for several complex algebra

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am looking for a generalization to fundamental theorem of algebra for several complex variables functions or systems. If such theorem exists, it should concisely relates the number of zeros of multivariate polynomial system to the order of each function of the polynomial system.

if such theorem exist please provide the proof or a proper citation.

Comment: Since the zero set of a complex polynomial in two variables could be homeomorphic to the 2-torus, and in particular could be uncountable, it is hard to see what one could hope to be true in this direction

Comment: i mentioned system of polynomial. so we have the same number of polynomial functions as the variables numbers. so it should have finite number of roots.

Comment: Bezout's theorem.

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for [Bezout's Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem)

Comment: would you please write the complete statement of the theorem in accordance to the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: @behradmahboobi Why don't you follow the link and see for yourself?

Comment: Links can break, and when they do, answers like this become useless. Less likely for Wikipedia entries, but still a good practice not to answer with just links.